# Native android/ios Component support in cross platform mobile technologies

Tags: android, ios, react-native, flutter, ionic-framework

I have to build one SDK which has a native language code in Android. now i have to give support that SDK to the all kind of cross-platform technology like RN, Flutter, Ionic, Phonegap etc..

I am search a short way to give support of native language SDK to cross-platform technologies.

Please help.

Comment: Kotlin i think have a new feature to right a single kotlin code and output an android and ios app but not sure about that, just heard about it some days ago. Google it maybe it coupd help..

Comment: for that you have to write different plugins for each platform.